# Use query hints to force lazy evaluation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query

```
declare @EvalRemarks bit
select @EvalRemarks = 0

select ID from table
WHERE (@EvalRemarks = 0) OR (AC_Remarks like '%' + @RemarksFilter + '%'))
```

Since SQL is a declarative language the query optimiser will decide itself which part he evaluates first.

Can I force it to evaluate a part first?  Is this possible with query hints?

When I execute the query now it takes 17 seconds, when I remove the where clause it takes 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @EvalRemarks BIT
SELECT @EvalRemarks = 0

DECLARE @RemarksFilter VARCHAR(30)
SELECT @RemarksFilter = 'test'

SELECT ID FROM dbo.[table]
WHERE @EvalRemarks = 0 
    OR (@EvalRemarks = 1 AND AC_Remarks LIKE '%' + @RemarksFilter + '%')
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Or try this -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ID FROM dbo.[table]' +
    CASE WHEN @EvalRemarks = 1 
        THEN 'AC_Remarks LIKE ''%' + @RemarksFilter + '%''' 
        ELSE '' 
    END

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: First one works perfect!  Thanks.  BTW Registered user of your SDAC comps :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because using Like with a wildcard at the beginning forces the query optimizer to do a complete table scan.  It can not use any indices that might be on the table.
If this is in a Stored procedure, You might try...

```
If @EvalRemarks = 0 select ID from table
Else select ID from table
     where AC_Remarks like '%' + @RemarksFilter + '%'
```